# How to amplify the recorded audio in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio-recording

Can someone tell me how I can amplify the recorded audio in iPhone and then play it simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What format do you have the audio in? Usually you can simply loop over the samples and multiply them:

```
static const float gain = 2;
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<kNumberOfSamplesInBuffer; i++)
    buffer[i] *= gain;
```

And you probably have to take arithmetic overflow into account, making sure the multiplied values don’t exceed the type range:

```
amplified = MIN(MAX_TYPE_VALUE, MAX(MIN_TYPE_VALUE, sample*gain));
```

If you still yet have to pick a recording API, I think you can use [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). There’s a plenty of sample code on recording with AQS and you can easily touch the samples there.

Comment: Zoul, I have not decided how I am going to record the audio. Can u you suggest me what I can use to use the suggestion you have made?

Comment: Hi Zoul, Can we amplify sound with specific frequency?

Comment: Yes, we can, but I don't know how, as my sound programming skills suck. I guess there's going to be some FFT involved, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

set following property to AVAudioSession.

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;   

AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,          
                             sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```